# Using double url tag in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I got two urls.py file

first one is for project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls , name = 'admin'),
    path('',homeView, name='home'),
    path('post/',post, name='post'),
    path('post/',include('post.urls'), name='posturl'),
    path('student/',studentM, name = 'student' ),
    path('student/',include('student.urls') , name='studenturl'),
    
]
```

second one is url for app

```
 urlpatterns = [

    path('index', post_index, name = 'index'),
    path('details/' + '<int:id>', post_detail, name = 'detail'),
    path('create', post_create, name = 'create'),
    path('update', post_update , name = 'update'),
    path('delete', post_delete , name = 'delete'),

]
```

I am trying to reach the adress like
**:8000/post/details/5**
but when i try to use in html

```
<a href = "{ % url 'post.detail' %}"> =>> {{post.id}}</a> 
<a href = "{ % url 'detail' %}"> =>> {{post.id}}</a>
<a href = "{ % url 'post' %}"> =>> {{post.id}}</a>
```

None of these are not working I got 404 error.

How can I reach the link which I want

```
def post(request):
    context = {
    }
    return render(request,'post/post.html',context)

def post_detail(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    context = {
        'post' : post
    }
    return render(request,"post/details.html",context)
```

Comment: Post detail is expecting an id which you are not passing from template. Also urls are not well designed as per namespacing is concerned please go through official document for the same https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/.

Meanwhile you can check for this line and try to figure out for others too:

<a href = "{ % url 'detail' %}"> =>> {{post.id}}</a>

Use:
<a href="{% url 'detail' id=post.id %}">{{post.id}}</a>

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you are tryng to access this url pattern:

`path('details/' + '<int:id>', post_detail, name = 'detail'),`

which can be written like this:

`path('details/<int:id>/', post_detail, name='detail'),`

if im correct, you should use this in your html a tag:

`<a href="{ % url 'appname:detail' post.id %}">text for the link</a>`

also, try not to do this:

```
path('post/',post, name='post'),
path('post/',include('post.urls'), name='posturl'),
```

it is better practice creating the `post` view inside your app, and then your urls.py are going to look like this:

```
# this is the project urls file
...
path('post/', include('post.urls')), # dont need a name here, you are not going to reference this
...
```

```
# this is the app urls file
...
path('', post, name='post'), # this is going to accessed as localhost:8000/post
path('index', post_index, name = 'index'),
path('details/<int:id>', post_detail, name = 'detail'), # this is going to accessed as localhost:8000/post/details/the_id_of_the_post
path('create', post_create, name = 'create'),
path('update', post_update , name = 'update'),
path('delete', post_delete , name = 'delete'),
...
```

Hope I've helped, if you still have any questions, feel free to contact me.